# Program crashes when integer is not 0, 1 or 2

Tags: ios, swift

I am a complete beginner to all things programming, so please forgive any blatant mistakes that you may find. I am writing a program that takes an input number and tells the user whether or not the number is a prime.

```
@IBOutlet weak var textfield: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

@IBAction func button(sender: AnyObject) {
    if (textfield.text.isEmpty) {
        label.text = "Please enter a number!"
    } else if (textfield.text == "0" || textfield.text == "1"){
        label.text = "The answer is undefined."
        textfield.text = nil
    } else {
        var input = textfield.text.toInt()
        if (input! % 2 == 0 && input! != 2) {
           label.text = "The number is not prime, one of its divisors is 2."
            textfield.text = nil
        } else if (input! == 2){
            label.text = "The number is indeed prime!"
            textfield.text = nil
        } else {
            var factor = 3
            while (factor <= input) {
                if (input! % factor == 0 && input! != factor) {
                    label.text = "The number is not prime, one of its divisors is \(factor)"
                } else if (input! % factor != 0){
                    factor += 2
                } else if (input! % factor == 0 && input! == factor) {
                    label.text = "The number is indeed prime!"
                    textfield.text = nil
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

My code looks like this, but crashes if the input is anything that is not 0, 1, or 2. I know there are better ways to write this program but I just want to figure out what exactly is wrong with this one. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you post the message you get when your code crashes?

Comment: It doesn't REALLY crash, the app freezes and stops working until I reset it, so there's no error message in the XCode log.

Comment: Sounds like an infinite loop.  `factor` is **always** <= `input`

Comment: But shouldn't the program add 2 to "factor" every time the factor doesn't go into the input evenly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the cases where you are updating the `label.text` you are not incrementing the `factor` which leads to an infinite loop.  Add a `break` to those cases to break out of the while loop and all will be well:

```
            while (factor <= input!) {
                if (input! % factor == 0 && input! != factor) {
                    label.text = "The number is not prime, one of its divisors is \(factor)"
                    break
                } else if (input! % factor != 0){
                    factor += 2
                } else if (input! % factor == 0 && input! == factor) {
                    label.text = "The number is indeed prime!"
                    textfield.text = nil
                    break
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

It not your swift. It is your programming logic. Your are not crashing, you are hanging in an infinite
 loop.

put a println in you while loop.
while (factor <= input) {
                    println ("Factor (input! % factor)")

Factor 0
Factor 0
Factor 0
Factor 0

You never end up incrementing factor. In my test case I enter 3 as the input.

David

Answer (score 0):

I think the input return a optional variable.

```
var input = textfield.text.toInt()
//and you force unwrap the input on the this statement:
 if (input! % 2 == 0 && input! != 2) {}
```

I think it crashed on here if the text is not number.
Take a look of the extension of `String`

```
extension String {

    /// If the string represents an integer that fits into an Int, returns
    /// the corresponding integer.  This accepts strings that match the regular
    /// expression "[-+]?[0-9]+" only.
    func toInt() -> Int?
}
```